# Terraform string functions trim, trimsuffix, trimprefix all reporting not found in 0.12.16 from console

Tags: terraform

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/trim.html

trim
trimprefix
trimsuffix

on version 0.12.16 from the terraform console all report function not found.

```
$ terraform console
> trim("dave.", ".")

>  
Error: Call to unknown function

  on <console-input> line 1:
  (source code not available)

There is no function named "trim".
```

Comment: Found reason here. Hashicorp forgot to add it to the release - https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/23413

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found reason here. Hashicorp forgot to add it to the release - https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/23413. will be out in 0.12.17